# C++ program not returning a Value (Functions)

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, string-concatenation, function-definition

I want to write a program, to create a function that concatenates two strings to form a single string. However, my program is not returning any value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char* my_str_cat( char* s1, char* s2, char* combined ){
   for(int i = 0;i<strlen(s1);i++){
       combined[i]=s1[i];
   }
   for (int j=0;j<strlen(s2);j++){
       combined[strlen(s1)+j]=s2[j];
   }
   return combined;
}

int main(){
   char s1[100];
   char s2[100];
   char** combined = new char*;
   cout<<"Enter s1: "<<endl;
   cin.getline(s1,100);
   cout<<s1<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter s2: "<<endl;
   cin.getline(s2,100);
   my_str_cat(s1,s2,*combined);
   delete combined;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you never reserve any memory for `*combined`, which should probably be a `char *`, not a `char**`.

Comment: Why is `combined` a `char**` to begin with? Why not a plain `char*`? Or better yet, a `std::string`?

Comment: `std::string` has a `operator+` that concatenates. If you want to do this as an exercise you need to have some characters for the combined string, not just a pointer to characters

Comment: By the way, why not write some code to check results of `my_str_cat`?

Comment: i am getting an error when i try just char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
char** combined = new char*;
```

declares a pointer of the type `char **` that points to an allocated memory for an object of the type `char *`.

Dereferencing this pointer in this call

```
my_str_cat(s1,s2,*combined);
```

passes an uninitialized pointer of the type `char *` to the function `my_str_cat`.

And within the function this uninitialized pointer is used to access a memory that results in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate a memory for a character array large enough to store two concatenated C strings forming a new C string.

You could allocate the memory within the function itself.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

char * my_str_cat( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = std::strlen( s1 );
    
    char * result = new char[n1 + std::strlen( s2 ) + 1];
    
    std::strcpy( std::strcpy( result, s1 ) + n1, s2 );
    
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];
    
    std::cout << "Enter s1: ";
    
    std::cin.getline( s1, sizeof( s1 ) );
    
    std::cout << "Enter s2: ";
    
    std::cout << std::noskipws;
    
    std::cin.getline( s2, sizeof( s2 ) );
    
    char *combined = my_str_cat( s1, s2 );
    
    std::cout << combined << '\n';
    
    delete []combined;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter s1: Hello
Enter s2:  World!
Hello World!
```

Another approach of declaring and defining the function is when it is the user of the function that is responsible to supply the result character array to the function that will contain two concatenated strings.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

char * my_str_cat( char *result, const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return std::strcat( std::strcpy( result, s1 ) , s2 );
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];
    
    std::cout << "Enter s1: ";
    
    std::cin.getline( s1, sizeof( s1 ) );
    
    std::cout << "Enter s2: ";
    
    std::cout << std::noskipws;
    
    std::cin.getline( s2, sizeof( s2 ) );
    
    char *combined = new char[std::strlen( s1 ) + std::strlen( s2 ) + 1];

    std::cout << my_str_cat( combined, s1, s2 ) << '\n';
    
    delete []combined;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the same way as it is shown for the previous demonstrative program that is

```
Enter s1: Hello
Enter s2:  World!
Hello World!
```

Without using standard string functions and using only loops the function can be defined the following way.

```
char * my_str_cat( char *result, const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = result;
    
    while ( *s1 ) *p++ = *s1++;
    
    while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: what does ( result, s1 ) + n1 this do?

Comment: @Agitated_Mouse It seems you mean the expression std::strcpy( result, s1 ) + n1. The function strcpy returns a pointer to the first character of the character array result. But we need to add the second string to the end of the first string. So we calculate the target pointer as the initiai pointer plus the length of the copied first string.

Comment: so just for clarification `strcpy(result,s1)+n1,s2) first copies s1 into result, but how can we add n1(is it because s1 is an array?), and after adding n1 s2 is copied

Comment: @Agitated_Mouse It is a pointer arithmetic. The function strcpy returns a pointer to the first character of the array result. But the second string we have to copy at the address &result[n1] that is the same as result + n1.

Answer (score -2):

First thing first, it (would) return a value its, just not assigned to anything. to do so:

```
*combined = my_str_cat(s1,s2,*combined);
```

Also either pass combined by refrence, or dont pass it al all.

But it doesnt cause it crashes with a seg fault, because you refere to s1[i] while s1 is not initialized.
Im gonna correct that in C style cause your code is really just C with spice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    
void my_str_cat( char* s1, char* s2, char* &combined){
    int len = strlen(s1);
    combined = (char*)calloc(1, (len + strlen(s2)));
    strcpy(combined, s1);
    strcpy(combined + len, s2);
}

int main(){
   char s1[100];
   char s2[100];
   char* combined;
   cout<<"Enter s1: " << endl;
   cin.getline(s1,100);
   cout<<s1<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter s2: " << endl;
   cin.getline(s2,100);
   my_str_cat(s1,s2, combined);
   cout << combined << endl;
   delete combined;
   
   return 0;
}
```

(Tho this works, i had i feeling of missing something while writting this. Please let me know what is it if you know.)